# How to change Chrome extensions internal HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've done some looking around and couldn't find any solution to this problem.

I'm creating a Chrome extension, with a *manifest* that points to the opening file `home-times.html`. This works, though I want to redirect it internally to the other page `home-welcome.html` inside the extension so it loads another page INSIDE the extension.

I've read a lot of questions that refer to changing the current tab's page, though that's not what I am after.

---

#### Tests

By using the following code:

```html
<a href="home-welcome.html">test</a>
```

Opens a new tab, with the extensions page that I am trying to access in that new tab.

Comment: Are you trying to get the browser to open the link in a new browser tab? - using target blank would do that - `<a href="home-welcome.html" target="_blank">test</a>`

Comment: I'm not, I'm trying to open a new HTML page for the extension to load inside itself. @Andrew

Comment: `location.href = 'home-welcome.html'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, you want to change your popup  innerHTML, in this case I suggest using jQuery, to change original file to the result you want.

If you just want to open new tab, with your home-welcome.html, you can do this, in your popup.js :

```
window.open('home-welcome.html','_blank')
```

If none of this is what you are looking for, can you please provide an example, I will try to help.

Comment: That's it, thanks so much Davo. Greatly appreciate it.